# Remove padding/margin from JavaFX Label

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to remove the default space (padding/margin) that JavaFX label adds? I want to get rid of the space displayed between the black lines on the image below:

[image]

Source code:

```
public class LabelTest extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage)
    {
        final Group root = new Group();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 130, Color.WHITE);

        final GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        gridpane.setHgap(10);
        gridpane.setVgap(10);

        final Label label = new Label("Label");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size:44px;-fx-font-weight: bold;-fx-text-fill:#5E34B1;-fx-background-color:#ffc300;");
        GridPane.setHalignment(label, HPos.CENTER);
        gridpane.add(label, 0, 0);

        root.getChildren().add(gridpane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding `-fx-padding: -10 0 0 0;` to the list of your styles.

For more flexible solution you can use `FontMetrics` information:

```
FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(label.getFont());
label.setPadding(new Insets(-metrics.getDescent(), 0, 0, 0));
```

**NB:** You need to call that code after `scene.show()`. Before that graphics engine is not ready to provide correct metrics.

Comment: Is there a dynamic approach than hardcoding a value? I don't want to hardcode (-10 in your example) a value and later see that the actual text gets chopped off

Comment: is there any other control that I can use which doesn't add the padding by default but just the text?

Answer (score 9):

One of the more dynamic ways to do this is to use a `Text` instead of a Label and set the `boundsType` as `VISUAL`. This results in a Text without any padding on the any of the sides of the Text, irrespective of the font size.

```
Text text = new Text();
text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
```

Comment: Can't we set it using CSS?

Answer (score 4):

For me it was easiest to just use **setPadding**.

```
label.setPadding(new Insets(-2,0,0,0)); //top, right, bottom, left
```

This way I did not have to deal with the css-style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For more details see my post here [Substructure styling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016612/11373502)

You could also do it like this after the **stage.show()**.

With the example of an separator:

```
Separator separator = new Separator();
separator.setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-width: 1px;"
    + "-fx-border-color: black;"
    + "-fx-padding: 0px;"
    + "");

stage.show()
```

Do

```
Node line = separator.lookup(".line");
line.setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-insets: 0px;"
    + "-fx-border-width: 0px;"
    + "");
```

or this way index **0** because it has only one element at index 0 which is an Region with style calss **.line**

```
separator.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-insets: 0px;"
    + "-fx-border-width: 0px;"
    + "");
```