# Remove All Padding from Javafx Label

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I tried setting the padding to zero in css, but it only removed horizontal padding from the right and left.

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359852), but it didn't remove the padding on top.

```
.review-label { 
-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;   
-fx-font-size: 18px;
-fx-text-fill: #dfdfdf;
-fx-font-family: "Gnuolane Rg";
}
```

I played with negative numbers to remove the top padding, but this is so hard to tweak and **doesn't** work well with **layout changes.** Why isn't the top padding removed when setting it to zero? Is there a reason? and is there a solution for this?

Comment: Could you maybe share all the code in a JSFiddle or Codepen?

Comment: @SirExotic This is not a question about HTML/JavaScript. You cannot create a JSFiddle for JavaFX applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove padding/margin from JavaFX Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359852/remove-padding-margin-from-javafx-label)

Comment: @Sedrick
That's the only answer i could find, and it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: then it's time for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)