# How can i remove the space inside a Separator?

Tags: java, css, javafx, separator

I have created a `Horizontal Separator` in a `VBox`.

Following is the code:

```
Separator s = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
s.setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-width: 1px;"
    + "-fx-border-color: black;"
    + "-fx-padding: 0px;"
    + "");
getChildren().add(s);
```

I want to remove the space inside the `Separator`. So I set the CSS property `-fx-padding: 0px;` but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I do it??!!

Here is the image
[Separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfKZM.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "space inside a separator," but you can try setting its `prefHeight` to 0.

Comment: @MikaelF i've tried it but didn't work

Comment: Then you should clarify what you mean by "space inside a separator" (maybe give an example of what you're getting, and what you want?), this will help others help you.

Comment: @MikaelF i've added a screenshot

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your question correctly, and this may be a bit of a hack, but you can try setting negative margins on your `Separator`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359852/remove-padding-margin-from-javafx-label

Comment: @MikaelF yeah it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator consists out of two Elements.

The **Separator** root node with css class **separator**
and an child element **Region** with css class **line**

If you want to remove the line in the middle of the black box than you have to modify the region(**line**) child and set its border **insets** and **width** to *0px*

for example:

```
Separator separator = new Separator();
separator.setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-width: 1px;"
    + "-fx-border-color: black;"
    + "-fx-padding: 0px;"
    + "");

stage.show()
```

And than after stage.show() you will have access to its childern via **lookup** or **getChildrenUnmodifiable()**

```
Node line = separator.lookup(".line");
line.setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-insets: 0px;"
    + "-fx-border-width: 0px;"
    + "");
```

or

```
separator.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).setStyle(""
    + "-fx-border-insets: 0px;"
    + "-fx-border-width: 0px;"
    + "");
```

and third the option of [With metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361408/11373502)

```
FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(label.getFont());
label.setPadding(new Insets(-metrics.getDescent(), 0, 0, 0));
```

and fourth option of [With Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959465/11373502) which is not applyable for all Nodes and does not work in this case.

```
Text text = new Text();
text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
```

And as last option you could add an **CSS** file which changes the style of the **.line** class

App.css:

```
.line {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
    -fx-border-insets: 0px;
}

.separator {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
    -fx-border-insets: 0px;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

And than you just have to apply this css to your scene.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("App.css");
```

If you dont know about it  already maybe you should checkout [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) which is a good tool if you want to inspect JavaFx applications.

Comment: No problem hope it helps :D